# Rails has_many_belongs_to, has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 Models: Place, User, Reviews. Place and Users related with **has_many_belongs_to** - for favorites, and **has_many :through** - for reviews.

I want to insert to favorites some place, but this place inserted to reviews table, what is wrong?

Or create model Favorites?

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base 

   has_and_belongs_to_many :users

   has_many :reviews
   has_many :users, through: :reviews

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :places

   has_many :reviews
   has_many :places, through: :reviews

end


class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :place
end








class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

     def add_favorites
        if User.first.places.push(Place.find(params[:place_id]))
           render json: {desc:true, status:0, error:nil}
        else
           render json: {desc:false, status:1, error: "Problem insert to table places_users"}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try having different names for the associations? Right now both your favorites and reviewed places are called the same.

Try something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :favorite_places

  has_many :reviews
  has_many :reviewed_places, through: :reviews
end
```

And for the controller:

```
User.first.favorite_places.push(Place.find(params[:place_id]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use active record serializers to store a array of favorites ids in the User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :favorites
end

user = User.create(favorites: [1, 4, 8, 9])
```